# Is this the correct MVC route setup or is there another way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to reserve the root of my website to be for standard webforms and have the MVC pages in a subdirectory Views so I have the following..

```
           routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "Views/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

However, even though this works and I see a few work-arounds, I'm not quite happy that the RedirectToAction seems to direct me to the wrong page e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Takes me to `http://localhost/Views` which gives me a resource not found and the Index action on the HomeController doesn't fire. Is there a better way of implementing what I want here or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know `Views` is kind of a reserved name in ASP.NET MVC. It's an existing directory. You could set the `RouteExistingFiles` to `true` in your route definitions:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "views/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

Now when you navigate to `http://example.com/views` or `http://example.com/views/home`or `http://example.com/views/home/index` it will be the `Index` action of `Home` controller that will get executed.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of RouteExistingFiles and it works perfectly